# Could not recognize the JSON tag

Tags: json, google-cloud-vision

After I encode an image via base64 encoder and name it test.jpg, I create a JSON file (named like a.txt) like the following:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "test.jpg"
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, I use the curl command to pass that file:

```
$ curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=browser_key --data-binary @a.txt
```

It illustrates that the server could recognize the value in the image content. Could anyone help?

Comment: Did you notice there's one closing curly brace (`}`) to many in your JSON? Also, did you remove all whitespace in the JSON file?

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, each } correspond to the {. I just forget to add the first { in the topside in the question. According to the error information send by the google, the problem is that it does not recognize the value in the image-content[0].

Answer (score 2):

In *content*, you need to send the *base64-encoded file data* of the image, instead of the filename *test.jpg*.

Check the [Google Cloud Vision manual](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send base64 encoded file data. You can send an image url, but is not a good idea.

Here is a website with best practices:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/image-best-practices